# Script/Much Needed Assistance

Tags: sql, plsql

I have searched and looked through some of the questions about creating temporary tables and columns with no luck as they don't pertain to my issue. I've searched and changed my query around for hours and unfortunately haven't made any progress. I currently have four tables that I'm joining together.

In one of the tables, there is a column and in that column is a value which can be any of the following values such as 'A,B,C,D,E' that represents an answer to a question. For example, if the person answered 'A', then there is a description that matches that value. The problem that I have is that the description is not in the table or in the database for that matter so I can't select the column and display the description that correlates to each answer. I have been told by co-workers that I need to hardcode that into the query. Possibly use a CASE statement or a REPLACE? Would the query look something like this?

```
DECLARE 

--variables--

CURSOR C1 IS 

SELECT 
FROM 
WHERE

BEGIN

--would this be where the REPLACE GOES?--

OPEN
LOOP
FETCH 
INTO 
--variables--
EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND%

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()

END;
/
EXIT
```

Please excuse my question and if it is somewhat convoluted. I'm new to this site and to Oracle PL/SQL in general so any advice on how to go about structuring this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you store your answers in a different table, and instead of values A-E assign an integer and a question_id that would be connected by foreign key constraint with specific question_id with answer descriptions?

Comment: I should have included in my question that I'm restricted to just extracting data from the tables that already exist and that I cannot create or modify the tables. I'm in a position where I just got a job and I have restrictive rights for the time being. Is there anyone way I could accomplish this by creating a temporary table within the query?

Comment: Please provide sample date from your questions table and what result do you expect.

Comment: Okay, so I'll call one table the Person_Table, PersonStanding_Table, PersonExpiration_Table, and lastly the Question_Table. Note that the Question_Table has the 'question' being asked of the person and the 'answer' that they gave which is the 'A,B,C,D, or E'.

expected results:

(Bob, Rivers, 08997, Student, 01/16/18, Gamer, A)
What I want to add to that without having to create a new table (because I don't have access to do that) is a description next to the 'A' that is in the results. Next to 'A' in a separate column I want to put "Loves to game but only plays weekends'. 

Sincerely

Comment: @Consider Me , I apologize for not structuring my question in a way that was easy to understand. I went back and attempted to edit my original question but accidentally pressed 'enter' instead of 'shift + enter' to start a new paragraph. At that point, I was unable to edit my question because the 5 minutes I was allotted passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain exactly what you're looking for since you're not providing a test case.  My guess, however, is that you want a `case` statement as a part of your cursor definition.

```
SELECT <<other columns>>,
       (CASE question_table.question 
             WHEN 'A' then 'Loves to game but only plays weekends'
             WHEN 'B' then <<something else>>
             WHEN 'C' ...
             ELSE 'Translation Unknown' 
          END) as new_column_name
  FROM <<your tables>>
 WHERE <<your predicates>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That answered my question considering the insufficient information I provided.